# Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times No invocations performed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq

I'm trying to mock function like below:

```
AntiForgeryValidator a = new AntiForgeryValidator();
public void ValidateRequestHeader(HttpRequestBase request) 
{
    string cookieToken = "";
    string formToken = "";
    if (request.Headers["RequestVerificationToken"] != null)
    {
        string[] tokens = request.Headers["RequestVerificationToken"].Split(':');
        if (tokens.Length == 2)
        {
            cookieToken = tokens[0].Trim();
            formToken = tokens[1].Trim();
        }
    }
    a.Validate(cookieToken, formToken);
    //AntiForgery.Validate(cookieToken, formToken);
}
```

So I created interface:

```
public interface IAntiForgeryValidator
{
    //void ValidateRequestHeader(HttpRequestBase request);
    void Validate(string cookieToken, string formToken);
}
public class AntiForgeryValidator : IAntiForgeryValidator
{
    public void Validate(string cookieToken, string formToken)
    {
        AntiForgery.Validate(cookieToken, formToken);
    }
}
```

And add new code to the test project:
Mocking Http Request:

```
Mock<HttpRequestBase> Request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
Request.SetupGet(x => x.Headers).Returns(new System.Net.WebHeaderCollection{
    {"RequestVerificationToken", "RequestVerificationToken"}
});
```

And mock validate method:

```
Mock<IAntiForgeryValidator> antiForgeryMock = new Mock<IAntiForgeryValidator>();
antiForgeryMock.Setup(m => m.Validate(
    It.IsAny<string>(),
    It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Callback((string cookieToken, string formToken) =>
        {
            // call back
        });

antiForgeryMock.Verify(m => m.Validate(
        It.IsAny<string>(),
        It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once());
```

This is all code I managed to create using answer found on this page.
But I'm still getting error like in the topic.
I suppose that all its caused by this lines:

```
.Callback((string cookieToken, string formToken) =>
        {
            // call back
        });
```

But I have no idea what should I put there. Reading `Moq` docs didn't help either.

@update:
Trying to done this like creating fakeRepository

```
private IAntiForgeryValidator fakeValidation;
fakeValidation = antiForgeryMock.Object;
```

Function when I'm trying to fire tests:

```
[TestMethod]
public void EditPost()
{
    var data = default(Device);
    var result = DC.Edit(data);
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
}
```

@Update two:
added new code:

```
DC.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(context.Object,new RouteData(),DC);
```

Now If I comment out `Veryfy` code works and is passed to controller. But still not working uncommented

Comment: How do you pass mock to object you are testing?

Comment: Since `AntiForgeryValidator.Validate` is called just once and returns void, there is probably little reason why you would want to call `Setup` on it as you can `Verify` the call. However, I've never found that calling `Setup()` would interfere with the `Mock.Verify`, so I don't think it is that. As per `Sergey`, please show the code like `var sut = new ValidateRequestHeader(antiForgeryMock.Object);` and `sut.ValidateRequestHeader(fakeRequest)`

Comment: I Updated question with code you were asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the antiForgeryMock.Verify() after you've run your test action.  A test usually looks like this:

```
// arrange
var myMock = new Mock<MyInterface>();
myMock.Setup(...);
var mySut = new Sut(myMock.Object);

// act
mySut.DoSomething()

//assert
myMock.Verify(...);
```

As mentioned in the comments, you don't need a Setup for your test, so you will skip that part.